# How to add Foundation to WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, zurb-foundation

I've searched the web on how to add Zurb's Foundation to a WordPress site, and currently I'm using the following in the end of functions.php:

```
function enqueue_foundation() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'foundation-css', get_template_directory_uri() .   '/css/foundation.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'foundation-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/foundation.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'foundation-jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_foundation');
```

I've checked the site (still local) source code, and it seems the JavaScript and CSS files are being added, but the jQuery file isn't. Also, with or without adding the jQuery file, the site's theme is breaking. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you using the version of jQuery bundled with Foundation, rather than the one that comes with Wordpress, you might need to adjust the path to `/js/vendor/jquery.js`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that this is the jQuery file I'm using. I've all JavaScript files directly in the js folder, skipping the vendor directory.

Comment: Maybe you need to de-register the built in wp jQuery first,  wp_deregister_script('jquery'); and load the foundation jQuery before the foundation.js using the dependencies parameter in wp_enque_script, (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) e.g. use wp_enqueue_script( 'foundation-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/foundation.min.js', array('foundation-jquery'));

Comment: BTW, If you ever need a starter Foundation theme for WordPress this is great. https://foundationpress.olefredrik.com/

Comment: @r8n5n: thanks, I tried using the statement you provided but I didn't de-register jQuery because I read here in the forum that there is something like a "non-conflict" mode in WordPress. It didn't work, thanks though.

Comment: The reason that you need to de register jquery is bacause WP already loads it so if you are using the foundation version too it will be loaded twice. The no-conflict is to do with having to use jQuery rather than $... jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    // $() will work as an alias for jQuery() inside of this function
    [ your code goes here ]
} );, Check the network tab in dev tools to see if jQuery is loading twice with or without using the de_register_script function. Also try susing the dependencies paramater and check the dev tools console for any JS errors.

Comment: Thank you. I've done the de-registering, but the layout is broken again.